# Is there any specific pattern Google Engine is using to show knowledge box?

Tags: seo, google, google-search, search-results

I search for "Uber Coupons" and I see results coming up in table format, what are the parameters on which google is showing knowledge box in search engine page results?

[image: For Reference]

Comment: That looks promotional / advertisement, rather than "knowledge"?

Comment: No, it is shown in SERP, no paid promotion, although it looks like promotional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem this is just one of Google's [featured snippets](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6229325?hl=en-IN). (from the "About this result" link in the bottom right hand corner of that "snippet".)

> ### Where does the answer summary come from?
>
> The summary is a snippet extracted programmatically from a webpage. What's different with a featured snippet is that it is enhanced to draw user attention on the results page. **When we recognize that a query asks a question, we programmatically detect pages that answer the user's question**, and display a snippet as a featured snippet in the search results.
>
> :
>
> ### How can I mark my page as a featured snippet?
>
> **You can't.** Google programmatically determines that a page contains a likely answer to the user's question, and displays the result as a featured snippet.

As to "what are the parameters on which google is showing" this - well, it's all part of Google's AI (black box) - so only Google really knows the answer to that.

You can provide "Feedback" if this snippet was helpful or not.

Comment: For what it is worth, I found that strong branding signals are required for this. You do not have to be a strong brand, just have strong signals starting with at least NAP, mark-up, etc. An anonymous blog will not work. However, a blog like MOZ or even less will. I have seen real opportunity in these featured snippets and have been studying them with targeted search lately. You also have to have content that fits a particular mold. The title and URI must fit certain semantic/syntactic formats and have the snippet easily found with a similar profile.

Comment: I would love to write an answer on this, however, I just started my analysis on this just a few days ago. Believe it or not, there is a road-map! Some parts are simple, and others take a bit to explain since it is about semantic linguistics - though I am finding Google is not as sophisticated as people believe. It seems a bit hodge podge. This means that the rules of the road will be kind of narrow and iffy at times. What I am finding is that it is incredibly easy to figure out how to target the page to search queries and Google will tell you what the proper search queries are if you dig.